# Why is this dxVectorMap not getting rendered in my fiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsfiddle, devextreme

I've got a `dxVectorMap` which is not getting rendered in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/pxsqaatk/).

- The `console.log` function says that `json` data is good enough
- There's no error as such
- The code seems to be good enough because the **zoom** control is showing up
- I've given `height` as well to `#container` div

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you provide the link to your fiddle?

Comment: @Sergey - [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/pxsqaatk/) it is

Comment: It looks like the answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using DevExtreme Charts with version 13.2 which released in 2013. [Documentation for this version available here](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxVectorMap/Configuration/?version=13_2) (you can change version to 13.2 in documentation settings).

there are scripts for 13.2:

http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/13.2.5/js/dx.chartjs.js
http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/13.2.5/js/vectormap-data/usa.js

For several years widget has many new features:
[14.1](http://js.devexpress.com/New/14_1/#HTML_5_Data_Visualization), [14.2](http://js.devexpress.com/New/14_2/#HTML_5_Data_Visualization), [15.1](http://js.devexpress.com/New/15_1/#HTML_5_JS_Data_Visualization), [15.2](http://js.devexpress.com/New/15_2/#HTML_5_JS_Data_Visualization)

and the settings structure has changed: [16.1 Documentation](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxVectorMap/Configuration/?version=16_1)

**2 ways:**

**1)** You should include more modern script versions:

chartjs: http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.1.4/js/dx.viz-web.js

and

usa.js: http://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.1.4/js/vectormap-data/usa.js

and your code will work

**or**

**2)** You should set [configuration for 13.2 version](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Visualization_Widgets/dxVectorMap/Configuration/?version=13_2)

Comment: Thanks for the support @SanR!!

Comment: I couldn't find this any where. Thanks